# iPhone app runs on iPad simulator, but the background is inverted!

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

i've installed new sdk 3.2 pre-release wich have iPad simulator, i have tried to launch an iPhone app created by me in iPad simulator; the main view of this app has an image as background; when launch it on iPad simulator this background(self.background = [[UImage..... ) it comes inverted, from top to bottom.

Any idea??

thanks in advance....:)

Comment: iPad development and the 3.2 SDK are under NDA.  Use the Apple Dev Forums for such questions; http://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: Also, if you do run into a bug with the new iPhone Simulator, be sure to report it at http://bugreport.apple.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an early bug in the SDK, which was fixed somewhere around Beta 3.